# How to add .dynsym section to static linked ELF file

Tags: linux, header, static-linking, elf

I have statically linked binary which doesn't have `.dynsym` section, and doesn't load any `.so` on start and `LD_PRELOAD` don't work. Is it possible to modify ELF headers of this file to activate loader on start adding some dummy import?

I don't have sources of this static linked binary